# How to expand and show elements in a listview?

Tags: android, listview

I have made a custom list view where each row has two textviews and a seek bar. I want to show initially only one text view and when the user clicks on an item the list should expand to full screen and show the textviews and seekbar.

This is what I have achieved until now:

```
public class ExpandableListActivity extends ListActivity
{
    Context context;
    private TextView mTitle;
    private TextView mDialogue;
    private SeekBar seekbar;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        context = this;
        // Use our own list adapter
        setListAdapter(new ListAdapter(this));
    }


    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
    {

    }


    private class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        public ListAdapter(Context context)
        {
            mContext = context;
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return mTitles.length;
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
            View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listlayout, null, true);
            mTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            mDialogue= (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            seekbar = (SeekBar)rowView.findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
            mTitle.setText(mTitles[position]);
            mDialogue.setText(mDialogues[position]);

            return rowView;
        }

        private Context mContext;

        String [] mTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.state_name);
        String [] mDialogues = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.capital_name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ExpandableListActivity or ExpandableListView. 
http://techdroid.kbeanie.com/2010/09/expandablelistview-on-android.html

Comment: some way to achieve by not using it

Comment: i dont want to use expandablelistview as it is not solving my purpose. please see if it can be done  or is there some way that i can inflate another layout on click of an item in listview which considts of 2 textview and a seekbar

Comment: You could, but as I said, it will be more complex. You can start out with maintaining a flag for each item in the list, and making a specific part of the convertView hidden or visible based on that flag.

Comment: and how to achieve the expansion of an item to full screen on click of that item and on second click again reducing its size to normal

Comment: By clicking set the flag to true and false, and depending on that, hide or show the items.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to take a look at the [ListView tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html).  Your `getView()` may work but its not very effective at using the existing API. Then implement `onListItemClick(...)` with the desired behavior. Additionally, as [Kumar Bibek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/220579/kumar-bibek) wrote, you may want to take a look at ExpandableListView.